# SOLR Java APi - Adding multiple condition

Tags: solrj

I am using Solr API to index the records and for search functionality.  I am using the following code to search through

```
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("q", "country_id:("+id+")");
```

I would like to add one more parameter like `state_id` and I would like to do logical AND/OR operations and depending on the result the records should be retrieved. I searched through Google, but could not find a way to combine the conditions. Is it possible through the SOLR api? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can make Your Query as Following.....

String qr="cstm_text:"+"devotional";

SolrQuery qry = new SolrQuery(qr);

qry.setIncludeScore(true);

qry.setShowDebugInfo(true);

qry.setRows(1);

qry.setFacet(true);

ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();

params.set("qt", "/spell");

params.set("spellcheck", "on");

params.set(MoreLikeThisParams.MLT,true);

qry.add(params);